# Display ODD red and EVEN Green in PHP tables

Tags: php, html, css

I made a simple table math calculator.

Only now I want when you echo the number the ODD numbers are red and the even numbers display green.
Is this possible with css ? or do I have to rebuild the whole code ?

### **Code HTML + PHP**

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
       <center>
       <form action = "pagina2.php" method = "post">
      <input name = "invoer" type = "text" value = "">
      <input name = "knop" type = "submit" value = "Verstuur">
      </form>
      </center>
      </body>
      </html>

//PHP

      <html>
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
<body>

      <center>
      <?php
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")



    {
        if (isset($_POST['invoer']))
    {
        if (is_numeric($_POST['invoer']))
    {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        echo $i . " x " . $_POST['invoer'] . " = " . ($i * $_POST['invoer']) . "<br />";
       }
    }
            else
       {

            echo "Vul een getal in!";
      }
  }
    else
  {

            echo "Niks ingevoerd!";
  }
 }

 ?>
 </center>
  <br>
   <center>
   <input action="action" type="button" value="Opnieuw" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Greetings.

Comment: Use the `:odd` and `:even` modifiers.

Comment: is any given solution work?

Comment: Lovely formatted code, a pleasure to read.

Comment: Is it also possible that the PHP script reads the CSS file for what colour tot choose by the number ?? you asked in solution this. Yah it is possible. if you want to know let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this echo statment

```
echo $i . " x " . $_POST['invoer'] . " = " . ($i * $_POST['invoer']) . "<br />";
```

To

```
$x=$i . " x " . $_POST['invoer'] . " = " . ($i * $_POST['invoer']) . "<br />";

if($x % 2 ==0 )
{
    echo '<font color="green">'.$x.'</font>';
}
else  echo '<font color="red">'.$x.'</font>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use modulas to shorten your code

```
  $number % 2 == 0 #means even
```

Then use a css class like .odd or .even and inject that into your template

Comment: You can shorten it by just removing the `== 0` - the boolean of `0` or `1` is `false` and `true` respectively, so just `$number % 2` will work

Comment: Don't forget to wrap that in an if then

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the variable $i:

```
echo '<div style="color: '.($i%2==0 ? 'green' : 'red').">". $i . " x " . $_POST['invoer'] . " = " . ($i * $_POST['invoer']) . "</div><br />";
```